# Jquery .attr doesn't load all images every time page loads

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to load a long list of images into a static HTML using Jquery src attribute. I also have multiple of such elements on my page, so this is just the biggest list as a sample. A problem is that not all images get loaded when I click the button. But if I reload the page and click on that button again - all of them get loaded well. And it happens randomly, it might be only 5 of them loaded or 7 or 8 or all of them. What could be the problem here?

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#mashup').click(function() {
        $('#mashupwindow').fadeIn(function() {
            $('#galleryone').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_20.jpg');
            $('#gallerytwo').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_1.jpg');
            $('#gallerythree').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_2.jpg');
            $('#galleryfour').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_3.jpg');
            $('#galleryfive').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_4.jpg');
            $('#gallerysix').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_5.jpg');
            $('#galleryseven').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_6.jpg');
            $('#galleryeight').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_7.jpg');
            $('#gallerynine').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_8.jpg');
            $('#galleryten').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_9.jpg');
            $('#galleryeleven').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_10.jpg');
            $('#gallerytwelve').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_11.jpg');
            $('#gallerythirteen').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_12.jpg');
            $('#galleryfourteen').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_13.jpg');
            $('#galleryfifteen').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_14.jpg');
            $('#gallerysixteen').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_15.jpg');
            $('#galleryseventeen').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_16.jpg');
            $('#galleryeighteen').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_17.jpg');
            $('#gallerynineteen').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_18.jpg');
            $('#gallerytwenty').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_19.jpg');
            $('#gallerytwentyone').attr('src', 'img/previews/13_1_21.jpg');
            $('#videoframe').hide();
            $('#captionone').html('...');
            $('#captiontwo').html("...");
            $('#captionthree').html("...");

            $('#mashupwindow').html($("#tableToClone").clone());
        });
    });
});
```

And here is html mockup, my jquery gets pushed into:

```
<div id="mashup"></div>
<div id="mashupwindow" class="mainscreen irbispanel"></div>
<div style="display:none">
    <table id="tableToClone" class="ts">
        <tr>
            <th class="ts-yw4l" rowspan="3">
                <img id="galleryone" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="gallerytwo" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="gallerythree" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="galleryfour" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="galleryfive" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="gallerysix" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="galleryseven" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="galleryeight" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="gallerynine" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="galleryten" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="galleryeleven" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="gallerytwelve" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="gallerythirteen" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="galleryfourteen" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="galleryfifteen" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="gallerysixteen" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="galleryseventeen" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="galleryeighteen" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="gallerynineteen" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="gallerytwenty" src="" class="previewing">
                <img id="gallerytwentyone" src="" class="previewing">
                <iframe id="videoframe" src="" class="previewing"></iframe>                             
            </th>
            <p id="captionone"></p>
            <p id="captiontwo"></p>
            <p id="captionthree"></p>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and here is css part responsible for styling them and fading them in, just in case:

```
.previewing{
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    width:600px;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style:none;
        -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
       -moz-animation: fadein 2s; 
        -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
         -o-animation: fadein 2s; 
            animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Comment: I just tried replacing it after content list and changed it to .show - same result. It doesn't load everything from time to time.

Comment: you have 2 options here without using fadein in css ... 1st if you can change your images url   you can use .each() and set src to each of them ... 2nd  if you know both the number of images and its url you can use for loop and append them

Comment: Oh you mean that. Well I tried it without css fadein animation. Same result. I'm trying to preload all images for now, I'll see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried executing it without the fadeIn function?

I'm wondering if you may be suffering from a Chome rendering glitch. Try applying `-webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);` to your elements and see if that helps.

Otherwise, I would recommend trying to preload those images. If you're fading in the div and loading the images at the same time, you're going to have quite a bit of a delay before those images get loaded in, resulting in the div fading in with incomplete content.

Good luck!

EDIT:

Per our investigation, it seemed that the images were getting display: none applied to them for some reason. The solution to this is ensuring, before the src attributes are set, that they are all shown. Place this at the beginning of the fadeIn function:

```
$('.previewing').css('display','block')
```

Comment: Hi, could you specify, so instead of fadeIn I should try just .show?  And also, how to preload images? I would be glad to have them preloaded, but I don't know where to look.

Comment: There are a few great methods to preloading listed here: https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

I was actually suggesting testing it without the fadeIn entirely to see if that might be causing rendering issues with the images as they get loaded in. If that's the case, I think you're issue may be related to the Chrome rendering glitch I mentioned. Test in a few other browsers as well and see if you have the same issue.

Comment: I just tried Firefox and tried using .show instead. Same result, loads from time to time, but not every time.

Comment: Nah, I tried preloading too and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Hmmm -- I wonder if you're hitting a race condition here when you clone that table. Try doing this: `setTimeout(function(){$('#mashupwindow').html($("#tableToClone").clone());},0);` That table could be getting cloned before all of the attributes are set.

Comment: Same. I don't even know, really. I already turned off fadein effect, put all content .attr lists before .show of the div. Preloaded all images and used your settimeout function. Nothing helps. Maybe I should try downsampling those images, they weight around 50kb to 250kb each and since there are 50 of them loading, browser might be choking up or something...

Comment: When I look at those files in chrome console, their display is set to none for some reason.

Comment: I've been trying to reproduce this locally on my machine and cant. I'm trying it with an image that is 3.5MB, so I doubt it's an issue with the filesize. I wonder if your server might be restricting concurrent requests or if it may be hitting your server's memory limit?

Comment: Interesting... try throwing this at the beginning of your fadeIn function `$('.previewing').show()` maybe? Or `$('.previewing').css('display','block')` if you want to be explicit.

Comment: hm, I tried using $('.previewing').css('display','block'), they all load properly now, but it seems to be loading all images now. Let's say after the last one it adds images from other click event. But at least they all load now.

Comment: Ok it all works now, thanks to you, dear wizard! If you edit your answer and add there your $('.previewing').css('display','block') part, I will mark it as a solution. Thank you!

Comment: Hey! Nice! Glad I could help :) My answer has been edited.